# BigQuery - Windowing for stock ledgering

Tags: google-bigquery

I (think) I have an interesting windowing scenario, related to website stock availability tracking, to work through in terms of Standard SQL.  This is trying to build a stock position view over time based on events that push and pull from an 'on hand' quantity of stock for a given product

We have 3 event types related to this problem:

**StocklevelUpdated** (PUSH): At midnight every night we get a new update on onHandQty availability levels for a given product from the warehouse.  This basically is a hard 'reset' if the onHandQty count for each product as the new value for next day of trading.  (note: This actually sends a record every night even if there is no change).

**OrderAccepted** (PULL): Then during the course of the day, there are many 'OrderAccepted' events for products, which in this scenario has a negative value for the stock 'onHandQtyDelta' (now less to sell). -2 for 2 units of a product ordered.

**OrderCancelled**: There can be cancelleations as well for quantity of a product, this has a positive value for the 'onHandQtyDelta', as it add back into the available stock for sale)

Below is a tabluar view of a slightly simplified version of the data in time order of *what I want to achieve*  (note: this shows a single product however of course there are many).

[image]

**onHandQtyDelta** - The change to the onHandQty as a result of this event

**onHandQty** - This is the net positive at that point in time *post* the delta affect.

Now although the above image shows all the values nicely ledgering out (although, note 29 is one of these midnight resets), in reality, *not all this data is available* and one of the values needs to be derived for each of these order event types. i.e 1 is missing.

**onHandQty**: The only rows in the actual dataset that have an absolute onHandQty defined is the 'StocklevelUpdated' events.  In essence this 'resets' this value for a product at midnight (e.g 29).  The journalling needs to basically trace back to the nearest of these.  However, onHandQtyDelta needs to be derived.

**onHandQtyDelta** Only the OrderAccepts and OrderCancelled events have this value which needs to be used to calculate the onHandQty.

So a picture speaks a thousand words, so the reality of the data to work with looks like below:

[image]

How to do this efficiently (given there are 10s of millions of rows) do this?

My thinking is to use windowing and 'lag' function to look back to the *previous* records onHandQty value to see what it was, and then do the addition or subtraction to come up with the new onHandQty value.

The problem is is then a recursive problem, as the previous event itself needs to look back to its previous and so on....until you get to a stocklevelUpdated event as this is the only event with an actual value to then work forward from.  But how to do this using windowing when the you dont know how far back to go to get such event - can be any number of OrderAccepts and Cancells in between (or none!)

Maybe something clever with arrays, collecting a given products rows into an array and doing some array agg functions?

I think Ive got stuckon thinking windowing is the way and maybe clouded by a simple solution!  Sorry for the all the detail, but didnt want to be vague on what I was needing help with.

Below gives the starting test dataset to work off (I just sorted it by product and time for purpose of creating the images)

```
WITH stock_changes AS (
SELECT
  "StocklevelUpdated" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-29T23:59:59") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_190035001612" AS productId,
  null AS onHandQtyDelta,
  23 AS onHandQty
UNION ALL (
SELECT
  "StocklevelUpdated" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-29T23:59:59") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_4545423454545" AS productId,
  null AS onHandQtyDelta,
  120 AS onHandQty)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT 
  "OrderAccepted" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-30T01:02:20") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_190035001612" AS productId,
  -2 AS onHandQtyDelta,
  null AS onHandQty)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT 
  "OrderAccepted" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-30T02:19:20") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_190035001612" AS productId,
  -3 AS onHandQtyDelta,
  null AS onHandQty)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT 
  "OrderAccepted" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-30T05:13:20") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_4545423454545" AS productId,
  -3 AS onHandQtyDelta,
  null AS onHandQty)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT 
  "OrderCancelled" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-30T13:02:20") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_190035001612" AS productId,
  +2 AS onHandQtyDelta,
  null AS onHandQty)
UNION ALL (
  SELECT 
  "OrderCancelled" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-30T11:02:20") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_4545423454545" AS productId,
  2 AS onHandQtyDelta,
  null AS onHandQty)
UNION ALL (
SELECT
  "StocklevelUpdated" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-30T23:59:59") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_190035001612" AS productId,
  null AS onHandQtyDelta,
  29 AS onHandQty)
UNION ALL (
SELECT
  "StocklevelUpdated" AS eventName, 
  Timestamp("2017-06-30T23:59:59") AS stockLevelEventAt,
  "PRODUCT_4545423454545" AS productId,
  null AS onHandQtyDelta,
  140 AS onHandQty)
)
SELECT *
FROM stock_changes
order by productId, stockLevelEventAt ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH stock_changes AS (
  SELECT "StocklevelUpdated" AS eventName, TIMESTAMP("2017-06-29T23:59:59") AS stockLevelEventAt,
    "PRODUCT_190035001612" AS productId, NULL AS onHandQtyDelta, 23 AS onHandQty UNION ALL 
  SELECT "StocklevelUpdated", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-29T23:59:59"),"PRODUCT_4545423454545",NULL, 120 UNION ALL 
  SELECT "OrderAccepted", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-30T01:02:20"),"PRODUCT_190035001612",-2, NULL UNION ALL 
  SELECT "OrderAccepted", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-30T02:19:20"),"PRODUCT_190035001612",-3, NULL UNION ALL 
  SELECT "OrderAccepted", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-30T05:13:20"),"PRODUCT_4545423454545",-3, NULL UNION ALL 
  SELECT "OrderCancelled", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-30T13:02:20"),"PRODUCT_190035001612",+2, NULL UNION ALL 
  SELECT "OrderCancelled", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-30T11:02:20"),"PRODUCT_4545423454545",2, NULL UNION ALL 
  SELECT "StocklevelUpdated", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-30T23:59:59"),"PRODUCT_190035001612",NULL, 29 UNION ALL 
  SELECT "StocklevelUpdated", TIMESTAMP("2017-06-30T23:59:59"),"PRODUCT_4545423454545",NULL, 140
)
SELECT
  eventName, stockLevelEventAt, productId, 
  delta AS onHandQtyDelta, IFNULL(onHandQty, onHand ) AS onHandQty
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    SUM(IFNULL(onHandQty,0) - delta) 
      OVER(PARTITION BY productId, format_timestamp('%Y-%m-%d', stockLevelEventAt) 
      ORDER BY stockLevelEventAt DESC 
      rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) AS onHand
  FROM (
    SELECT eventName, stockLevelEventAt, productId, onHandQty, 
      CASE 
        WHEN prev IS NULL THEN IFNULL(onHandQtyDelta, 0) 
        ELSE onHandQty - prev - delta 
      END AS delta
    FROM (
      SELECT *, 
        SUM(IFNULL(onHandQtyDelta,0)) OVER(PARTITION BY productId, format_timestamp('%Y-%m-%d', stockLevelEventAt) ORDER BY stockLevelEventAt) AS delta,
        LAG(onHandQty) OVER(PARTITION BY productId, eventName ORDER BY stockLevelEventAt) AS prev
      FROM stock_changes
    )
  )
)
ORDER BY productId, stockLevelEventAt ASC
```

Result is as below

```sql
Row eventName           stockLevelEventAt       productId    onHandQtyDelta onHandQty    
1   StocklevelUpdated   2017-06-29 23:59:59 UTC PRODUCT_190035001612    0   23   
2   OrderAccepted       2017-06-30 01:02:20 UTC PRODUCT_190035001612    -2  21   
3   OrderAccepted       2017-06-30 02:19:20 UTC PRODUCT_190035001612    -3  18   
4   OrderCancelled      2017-06-30 13:02:20 UTC PRODUCT_190035001612    2   20   
5   StocklevelUpdated   2017-06-30 23:59:59 UTC PRODUCT_190035001612    9   29   
6   StocklevelUpdated   2017-06-29 23:59:59 UTC PRODUCT_4545423454545   0   120  
7   OrderAccepted       2017-06-30 05:13:20 UTC PRODUCT_4545423454545   -3  117  
8   OrderCancelled      2017-06-30 11:02:20 UTC PRODUCT_4545423454545   2   119  
9   StocklevelUpdated   2017-06-30 23:59:59 UTC PRODUCT_4545423454545   21  140
```

Most likely can further be optimized  - but i more focused on getting logic implemented and less on optimizing

Comment: Mikhail wow thanks for this - Ill need to sit down and digest it a bit now, much appreciated.  Getting the right results first obviously is a great start, can then optimise for the circa 12 million rows this would be for.

Comment: sure. btw this query has really good chance to scale for your real data with millions rows - this depends on your productID/days/etc. distribution. you just try :o) and don't forget accept and vote if you will find appropriate

Comment: cool great to know!  Just going over the SQL with the full dataset.  If there was another column 'location' (2 values, 'UK' or 'US'), where in fact productId + location was unique, rather then just productId (i.e same productId, different location), how would this change?  I think Ive got it right by adding the location into the partitions and the order by but just wanted to check?  Also, sometimes we oversell, so the onHandQty can go negative (was previous 0, then we had an orderCreated, it goes negative then)....currently it shows as 'null'.  Awesome thanks!

Comment: i think you need to add location to partition by only. no need to to order at all